What is blocking HVAC airflow in my wall?
I tapped into an unused port on the plenum and ran an 8 inch flexible duct.  This goes 20 feet across the first floor attic, into a metal elbow, and then more 8 inch duct inside a wall up to the 2nd floor attic.  When I check where it goes into the wall in the downstairs attic there is a lot of airflow.  Whips my hair around.  When I check upstairs, 8 feet up, there is barely any airflow.  I have run a camera up and down the duct in the wall and it looks fine.  What is going on?

So checked for leaks?

Does airflow improve if you open a window? Or perhaps the door to downstairs? If you're pumping air into a space and the air has nowhere to go, air flow will be poor.

The hatch to the attic was open and there is a clear passage down the stairs to the return grill.  The duct in the wall has no real place to leak.  It is framed in and sheet rocked all around.

How is it you have an 8" duct in a wall? I suspect an area reduction there. Also, your use of the term "attic" to describe spaces on main and lower levels is confusing to me.

Hard to believe that the 8' of vertical run in the wall is the problem, unless there's a massive leak, or blockage, someplace.  In my previous house, the hot air furnace and cooling coil for the AC was in the basement.  A supply plenum went up 2+ stories to the attic where it branched out to feed registers in the ceilings of the 2nd floor bedrooms.  We had acceptable airflow in all the bedrooms, even when AC was being used.

What's going on is your air went through a 90 degree bend after traveling 20 feet in flexable duct. A 90 bend drastically reduces air flow just going through the bend. Then you have the  pressure drop due to lifting the air, cold air has mass, up the additional 8 feet into the attic. You can improve the air flow in the 90 degree bend by installing a bend with vanes in it.

Forgot to mention.  This is heating only.  No lifting cold air.  I had a suspicion about the bend being a problem.  I will experiment with that.  Any suggestions on a fix?

Heck, the flexible duct reduces air flow too.

@Huesmann  Yes it does but the OP states they had great flow after the 20 feet of flex so I left it out.

This afternoon I went into the attic and changed a few things.  I straightened out the duct and changed the angle so I could feed it inline with the vertical section.  I can now feel airflow from the upstairs vents!  I will have to wait and see if it is enough heat but it certainly is a big improvement.  Thank you for explaining this.  -- Jerry
